# Disallow `rm` to remove `*`

Tags: bash

**Note**: If you googled this by the title of this question, don't use this script unless you know what it is supposed to do.

This is a script in `bash` 3+ that I have used for long for preventing `rm *` and `rm -rf *` from accidentally invoked and removing important files by mistake. I put it in my `~/.bash_aliases`.

```
alias rm='set -f;rm'
rm(){
    if [[ "$-" == *i* ]]
    then
        if [ "$1" = "*" ] || [ "$2" = "*" ] || [ "$1" = "./*" ] || [ "$2" = "./*" ]
        then
            echo "Abort: refusing to remove *, please go to the parent folder and do rm <folder_name>/*" 1>&2
            set +f
            return 1
        fi
    fi  
    set +f
    /bin/rm -i $@
}

set +f
```

I would like to know whether there are any vulnerabilities and whether it can be improved.

Answer (score 11):

The vulnerability I see is that only the first two arguments are checked.  You could check all of them:

```
rm() { 
    [[ $- == *i* ]] && for arg
    do 
        if [[ $arg = "*" || $arg = "./*" ]]
        then
            # abort
       fi
   done
   # do the rm
```

This kind of checking will miss other dangerous wildcards like `**` or `?*`.  You can get safer checking by expanding `*` yourself, then see if the expanded arguments contain that same list of files:

```
# alias not needed here; we want globs to be expanded
rm() {
    declare -a star=(*)
    declare -a dotslashstar=(./*)
    if [[ "$@" == *"${star[@]}"*  ||  "$@" == *"${dotslashstar[@]}"* ]]
    then
         # abort
```

... but then you can't (for example) empty a directory full of temp files with `rm *.tmp`, if `*.tmp` and `*` match the same thing.

Comment: I love your idea of expanding `*` myself.

Answer (score 8):

#### Double-quote variables used in command parameters

This is a bug:

> ```
> /bin/rm -i $@
> ```

What will happen if you try to delete file `a b` (with space in the name)?
Most likely this:

> ```
> rm: a: No such file or directory
> rm: b: No such file or directory
> ```

Always write `"$@"` instead of unquoted `$@`.

Unfortunately, as you pointed out in a comment,
this will cause another problem:
arguments containing globs will be taken literally.
In short, it's difficult to have the cake and eat it too.

You could mitigate the problem by looping over the arguments,
and if you detect a glob, then expand it yourself:

```
for arg; do
    if [[ $arg == *[*?]* ]]; then
        expanded=($arg)
        echo rm -i "${expanded[@]}"
    else
        echo rm -i "$arg"
    fi
done
```

This still won't be perfect, because it doesn't handle the case when an argument contains both spaces and globs. A robust solution would take more effort, and not worth doing in Bash. (See [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48526731/641955) delegating the hard work to Python.)

#### Use `command` to bypass aliases

Don't worry about the absolute path of commands. Use `command` to bypass aliases:

```
command rm -i "$@"
```

#### Redundant file descriptors

In `echo "Abort: ..." 1>&2`, the file descriptor `1` is redundant, you can safely omit it.

#### Preserving the user's environment

This is a minor nitpick.
When the alias is executed, it will do `set +f`,
regardless of whatever was the original setting in the shell,
which may not be the same.
This is really just a minor nitpick, for the record.
I wouldn't care about this tiny impractical detail either.

Comment: I had an issue with patterns containing asterisk (e.g. `rm -f .*.swp`) and that's why I didn't quote `$@`. Your other advices are taken.

Comment: @WeijunZhou That's a good point. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 4):

### Don't call your function `rm`

If you start depending on this safety net, you'll eventually have an accident on a system with a standard `rm` (e.g. when you become root and find yourself using `dash` for admin tasks).

I'd suggest

```
weijun_rm() {
    # your safer implementation
}

rm() {
     echo "Disabled - please use weijun_rm instead" >&2
     return 1
}
```

This will train you not to use `rm` for deleting files.  When your function isn't available and you have to use the real `rm`, you will be on alert and extra careful to check the arguments.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. This is just an extra protection. I don't depend on this and I know what I am doing in most cases. Just in case I didn't get enough sleep and do sth silly ...

Comment: I guess anyone can accidentally brush Enter when typing `rm *~` or `rm *.o` or the like (I normally write `echo`, and only type the `rm` when I'm happy with the rest).  But perhaps my advice might be useful for others who aren't so disciplined.

Answer (score 1):

## Restore options properly

Instead of `set -f` in our alias and unconditional `set +f` in the function, we can save the current shell options using `set +o` to print them as commands:

```
fun() {
    restore=$(set +o)

    set -f        
    # ... and any other option changes
    # and perform the task

    # finally (instead of set +f)
    eval "$restore"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the version I am using after taking the advance of above answers. Only the core `if` is written.

```
if [[ $- == *i* ]]
then
    set +f
    for arg in "$@"
    do # We want to abort the whole command even if only some of the arguments contain dangerous patterns
        if [[ "$arg" == "*" || "$arg" == "./*" ]] # Can be replaced by a custom program written in Python etc. to detect dangerous patterns
        then
            #abort
            return 1
        fi
    done
    declare -a all
    for arg in "$@"
    do #We need to collect all arguments instead of `rm`-ing one by one otherwise `rm -rf file` does not work properly
        if [[ "$arg" == *[*?]* ]]
        then
            expanded=($arg)
            all+=("${expanded[@]}")
        else
            all+=("$arg")                                                                                                                                                                               
        fi
    done
    command rm -i "${all[@]}"
...
```